# How can I restrict desktop browser access to an iPhone web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, browser

I designed an iPhone web app that can also be accessed by the desktop. The design falls apart on the browser when it is only meant for the iphone. How can I stop users from accessing from a Desktop browser and only an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS media query to hide the contents for screens above a certain size, replacing it with a message that it's a mobile-only site.

Comment: I did that, but what should I put inside to say or do so that it cancels the sites features or something along those lines?

Comment: If you're hiding all the contents, those features aren't going to be visible or functional.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript you can use

```
var isIOSDevice = /(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test( navigator.userAgent ); // will be true or false
```

if you only want iPhone then remove iPad and iPod

If `isIOSDevice` isn't true then you can redirect them to your desktop friendly page.